# mac partition didnot display after shirinking partition c in windows 8.1

Tags: macbook-pro

I have mid 2012 macbookpro. I have installed yosemite 10.10.3 on it and installed windows 8.1 with bootcamp.
when i have started up with windows 8.1, i decided to shirink partition C to additional partition. 
i think i had mistake beacause after that the color of partition have changed. 
i reset the system, no mac and no windows not boot .when i hold  option key just show partition windows.
i have repaired the windows and came up, but unfortunatly partition mac didnt display and boot .
i have very important data on mac. please help me.

Comment: Golden Rule #1 - never let Windows anywhere near the partitioning on a Mac. It simply doesn't understand the way Boot Camp structures it to make Windows *think* it's in charge.

Comment: see if http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76402/resize-boot-camp-partition or http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66650/how-to-change-boot-camp-partition-if-is-set or  http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/127412/how-to-expand-bootcamp-boot-partition-to-previously-existed-ntfs-data-partition might help… & I hope you have backups